# Call object in template after _meta.get_fields()

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

So I have lots of models with relations to the parent model. Like this

```
class Part(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=550)

class Stock(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=550)

class StockArea(models.Model):
    area = models.CharField(max_length=550)
    stock = models.ManyToManyField(Stock, related_name='stockarea_stock')

class Si(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    si_unit = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Quantity(models.Model):
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    si = models.ManyToManyField(Si, related_name='quantity_si')
    part = models.ManyToManyField(Part, related_name='quantity_part')
    stockarea = models.ManyToManyField(StockArea, related_name='quantity_stockarea')

class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.FileField()
    part = models.ManyToManyField(Part, related_name='image_part')
```

When I want to have a detail view of a part, I want to show Name of part, Quantity, Image, stockarea etc.

So the viw looks like this for the detail view

```
def details(request, part_id):
    part = get_object_or_404(Part, pk=part_id)
    part = part._meta.get_fields()
    context = {
        'part': part,
    }
    return render(request, 'part/details.html', context)
```

The problem comes when trying to call for everything in the template.

I can show object with calling just part: `{{ part }}`

But I want to be able to call the name of the part, like: `{{ part.name }}`

I understand this would be troublesome since related fields also are called 'name'. So I thought I was gonna be able to call it like this: `{{ part.Part.name }}`
or when I want to show quantity: `{{ part:Quantity.quantity }}`

None is working. So my question is, how do I call the data from the object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `part` object you get is a model instance. You can use it as a model instance. So this just works:

```
{% for image_object in part.image_part.all %}
    <img src="{{ image_object.image.url }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

That is, after your remove this line:

```
part = part._meta.get_fields()
```

There's no reason whatsoever to do that. The occasions that you need access to _meta are rare.

Comment: This is not working. When I write only `{{ part }}`, I get the name of the part. So I guess it's not a model instance?

Comment: When you write {{ part }}, you call part.__str__(). So your model definition probably has `def __str__(self): return self.name`.

Comment: Yes, I added that to that model. Still I get not retun of value when writing your code example. Is there a way to look up what the model instance is containing?

Comment: But do you have images? `{{ part.image_part }}` should return something like "RelatedObjectManager". `{{ part.image_part.count }}` should show the number of images attached to the part. And just to reiterate: remove the line I mentioned.

Comment: `{{ part.image_part }}` gives **part.Image.None**. `{{ part.image_part.count }}` gives number 2. I have two images for that part. Also, if I write in the for loop `{{ image.image }}` I get the filename.

Comment: My bad! Fixing.

Comment: What is this magic? I always thought the name after **for** is a local name only for the loop, that could be anything and did nothing. Is it the **_object** that does the trick? Anyway thanks a lot. You know how to get the **id** of the image as well? Cause `{{ image_object.image.id }}` dif nothing.

Comment: No, I just renamed to make it clear that you get Image object instances. Your Image model has a field `image`, which caused me to make the error initially as I forgot to reference the image field of the image instance.